# power analysis for difference of means -- without examining distribution of difference of means

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power, standardization, type-i-and-ii-errors

I am interested in calculating the power of studies to detect differences of means with a z- or a t-test -- and in doing so without directly examining the sampling distribution of the difference of means. Is this possible? And if so, why does my attempt at it work only with one-sample tests, and not with two-sample tests?

Textbook recipes call on the reader to estimate power (or the rate of Type-II error) by examining the sampling distribution of the difference of means. To fix ideas, consider a two-sample, one-tailed z-test. The first sample is drawn from $N(\mu_1, \sigma_1)$; the second sample is drawn from $N(\mu_2, \sigma_2)$. The null hypothesis is $\mu_1 = \mu_2$; the alternative is $\mu_2 > \mu_1$. We are setting $\alpha$ to .05. Suppose that $\mu_1 = 5$, $\mu_2 = 5.05$, $\sigma_1 = 2$, $\sigma_2 = 3$, and $N_1 = N_2 = 100$. Then a textbook procedure is

1. Find $z_{.95}$. It's 1.645.
2. Find the standard deviation of the difference of means. It is $\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_1^2}{100} + \frac{\sigma_2^2}{100}}$ = 0.3606.
3. Find the product of the previous two terms. It is the smallest detectable difference of means -- in this case, 0.5931.
4. Consider the sampling distribution of the difference of means: $N(.05, .3606)$. Find the probability that a draw from this distribution is less than .5931. This probability -- the probability of a Type-II error -- is .934. In turn, the power of the study is .066.

The procedure makes sense to me, and simulations and power-calculating programs confirm the result. But many textbooks *also* try to convey intuition behind power analyses with figures like this one:

[image: textbook depiction of null and alternative distributions]

This sort of figure leads me to infer that we should be able to calculate power while examining only the distributions of the sample mean when the population has mean $\mu_1$ or $\mu_2$ -- that is, while examining only $N(\mu_1,~\sigma_1/\sqrt{N_1})$ and $N(\mu_2,~\sigma_2/\sqrt{N_2})$. This is the procedure that I have in mind:

1. Find the 95th-percentile value of the null distribution, $N(\mu_1,~\sigma_1/\sqrt{N_1})$. With the values given above, it is 5.329. The implication is that, under the null, we will observe values above 5.329 less than 5% of the time.
2. Consider the sampling distribution of the mean under $\mu_2$: $N(\mu_2,~\sigma_2/\sqrt{N_2})$. Find the probability that a draw from this distribution is less than 5.329. To judge by the figure, this probability seems as though it should be the Type-II error rate. And in turn, 1 minus this probability should be the power of the study.

But this procedure doesn't work:

```
qnorm( .95,  5.00, 2/sqrt(100))  # 5.329 
pnorm(5.329, 5.05, 3/sqrt(100))  #  .824, not .934
```

My intuition is failing. Why doesn't this alternative procedure estimate the Type-II error rate or the power of a z-test for the difference of means? (Doesn't the figure suggest that it should work?) And given that it isn't estimating those things, is it estimating any meaningful quantity?

The matter is complicated when I see that the alternative procedure *does* work for one-sample z-tests, in which we test a sample mean against a fixed mean (rather than another sample mean). Suppose, for example, that our sample has $N = 100$ and $\sigma=2$. In this case, the alternative procedure is

```
qnorm( .95,  5.00, 2/sqrt(100))  # 5.329
pnorm(5.329, 5.05, 2/sqrt(100))  #  .9185
power.t.test(100, .05, sd=2, type="one.sample", alt="one.sided")$power  # .0813
```

The alternative procedure leads to an estimated Type-II error rate of 1 – .9185 = .0815, which is almost exactly what we get from `power.t.test()`. Why does this procedure work for one-sample tests but not for two-sample tests?

Comment: I do not see anything wrong here: your two scenarios are simply different. The sampling distribution of the difference of means is not the same as the sampling distribution for the alternative hypothesis. In my book on detection limits, I have a figure like the one you show and, as you say, many textbooks have such a figure.

Comment: Thank you, @EdV. Your comment helps. / I've added material to the bottom of my post, showing that the alternative procedure works for one-sample tests. Would it be apt to say that it works in these cases because, when we consider one-sample tests, the second step of the procedure involves a distribution that is effectively the sampling distribution of the difference of means? After all, `pnorm(5.329, 5.05, 2/sqrt(100))` (in the second step) is equivalent to `pnorm(.329, .05, 2/sqrt(100))`. And in that latter command, I'm examining the sampling distribution of the difference of means.

Comment: Let me think about it a bit, but my initial take is to agree with your supposition. Of course, if one of the heavy hitters takes an interest, I will be all ears to what they have to say!